# Web Console and SQL Plus not syncing in Oracle XE 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have Oracle XE 10g installed in my Windows 10 OS. I am able to connect both Web Console and SQL Plus command line to the database. The issue is operations done in SQL Plus command line are not reflecting in Web UI. But whatever doing in Web UI is reflecting in SQL Plus command line. I am using the default SYSTEM user. Why this issue coming?

SQL Plus version - SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0
Oracle version - Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you executing a COMMIT statement in sqlplus after commands?

Comment: What kind of operations? You shouldn't generally be doing anything as `SYSTEM` - if you are creating your own tables and inserting data (and missing `commit`, which does seem likely) then you should create a new user/schema instead of using a built-in one.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: I have tried by giving commit after the insert DML operation. Still, it is not reflecting in Web UI.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I am using DML operations like select and insert. I am a complete beginner in setting a database from scratch. For the time being, I have used SYSTEM schema. I will create and use my schemas going forward. I have tried by hitting commit after statements in SQL*Plus, unfortunately, that also didn't work.